# C# - Best way to handle saving multiple configurations (and accessing data live)

Tags: c#

So I've seen many questions that talk about the best method to store settings but haven't really seen any that deal with my situation.

Basically my app today has one settings tab with about 75 options/settings.  A user is able to basically have different "copies" of these settings (think: dropdown that when you select it, all 75 options are set to whatever was in that associated .xml file).

Right now I just store settings using XML.  The problem is that when my application needs to ACCESS a setting, it is literally accessing the UI directly (checkboxes, etc...)

My question: Should I basically created a "has changed" event for every control, and then update the appropriate setting structure (and only save when the user hits save)?

I'm worried that I shouldn't be accessing the UI directly, and it's doing that today ALL over the app.  I want to be sure that my new solution is appropriate/how C# was designed.

Thanks in advance!
~ Josh

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have a class that represents a configuration.  Serializing to/from XML allows you to store it in a file or database.

A static singleton can provide the application with the currently active configuration's values.  The application should not be checking the UI elements on a non-visible form to get the settings each time one is needed.

Designing the settings form so that it handles a instance of a configuration allows it to be used to display/update the active configuration or a saved configuration.  It ought to simplify letting a user load a configuration, modify it, and save it as a new configuration.

And 75 is, as a rule, a lot of settings for a single tab to manage.

Comment: It's not for one tab :)  There are like 11 tabs on my settings form.  How would you recommend I design the settings form though? Should I have a "changed" event on each form element? (like text box, check box?)  Seems tedious but I think would work well.

Comment: To some extent it's your choice.  Is the application performing actions on other threads that should be affected as soon as a box is checked?  Are there interacting settings, e.g. selecting a manufacturer may change the choices of cars?  In some cases it is easier to let the user change everything they want, then validate while saving the data.  It avoids having users try to find the order in which they must change individual settings to achieve the overall change they want.  That said, I lean toward gathering all of the data at form exit, ideally when the user clicks Save/OK/Update.

Comment: Perfect that's helpful, I like your idea of not doing anything until they hit save.  I'll gather data then - thanks so much!